# How to select a distinct when multiple columns are needed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, distinct

I've got a contacts table that has a column named Account. Each account is for a different employee; however, each employee has some of the same email address and or two different employees can the same email address if they're both working with the same customer.

What i need to do is select all the columns from the contacts table but only return distinct email addresses.

In other words i need to select all the records but I do not need to have duplicated records and the only way to know if the record is duplicate is by the email address.

I've provided a snap shot of the table and the columns.

[image: distinct needed]

**When returning the records / rows I do not want to have two rows with the same email address.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `not exists` query to select the row with the lowest id for each unique email.

```
select c1.*
from dbo.Contacts c1
where not exists (
    select 1 from dbo.Contacts c2
    where c1.Email = c2.Email
    and c2.ID < c1.ID
)
```

For the row with greatest id change `c2.ID < c1.ID` to `c2.ID > c1.ID`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care which row, then use `row_number()`.  The following gets an arbitrary row:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by email order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from Account a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want a particular row, such as the first or last (based on the primary key), then just use the appropriate `order by` (in the `partition` clause):

```
order by id asc -- get the first
order by id desc -- the the last
```